# Pentaho rows to variables

Tags: loops, variables, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to create a transformation which takes values from a table input (lets say, 10 rows) and in turns creates variables from the values from the rows. For each row in the original set, I then need to do a new transformation using the variables.

How can I loop through a bunch of rows, one by one, reading it into variables which will be used later in a transformation of its own?

Comment: It's not the end of the road but ..
After input add "Add value fields changing sequence": 1, 2, 3 etc
--- youre now able to deal with noname-rows ---
Add a Dummy
From here add a few Filter-Steps (up to 10 i.e)
1. Filter Step, Filter =1
Now set a "Set Variables"-Steps an give field 1 a variable-name like the input of row 1

helpful as a beginning?

The last step is tricky, cause its not within this transformation, but you can build a job ans add this transformer as "variable-definition-transformer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looping in PDI is a bit complicated.

You can use the following proceed:

1. Create a job in PDI. First execute a Transformation, which reads or
   generates the rows you need and use the "Copy rows to result" step.
2. After that create a execute Job step in the first Job. Here you have
   to check the "Execute for every input row" Option in the "Advanced"
   settings of the job. In this job you create and execute the final
   Transformation, which is transforming your data.
3. In this transformation you have to use the "get rows from result".
   Here you can finally read the variables you have defined before.

Hope i could help you.
Best regards.

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct since this is the way I ended up doing it.